# Can I download genuine Ubuntu from www.ubuntu.com?

Tags: wireless, bluetooth

Can I download the genuine version of Ubuntu from http://ubuntu.com? or do I need to make it genuine after downloading just like Microsoft Windows?

Comment: What do you mean genuine? Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: `Genuine` is terminology only used on `Windows` where you have license keys versus pirated copies. Linux distributions like Ubuntu do not have license keys and restrictions, therefore all Linux distros are `genuine`.

Comment: RIP ---- ENGLISH

Comment: yes it is geninue if you downloaded it from official ubuntu page,.. and to find if your hardware drivers are installed or not use live usb/dvd...

Comment: what i mean to say that is while installing ubuntu updates is on by that it may crash my ubuntu like when windows crashed by doing updates on so that  i asked whether ubuntu is asked

Comment: @user288093: No Ubuntu is completely different from Windows. It won't crash without a good reason. Most drivers are already available in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Ubuntu is always genuine!

> Ubuntu is legally free in all conditions.

- Microsoft refers Genuine to as 'None Pirate' version of its Operating System (Windows).
- It would be legal if you install it on as many of your computers or even to let your friends or family install it on theirs.

After Edit:
You mean 'Activation'. No since there is no licence granted to individual users unlike Windows, so you are not required to activate. You don't need any CD/Licence keys.

Comment: Though it is always 'free' does not mean that the download could be corrupted. Hence an md5checksum could be at place.